# Formula Expression is required on the action attributes. when calling Java script function from command button

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Whenever a cancel button is clicked I want to take the user to the previous page.

SO here I am calling the JavaScript function but it is throwing an error **Formula Expression is required on the action attributes**

Page :

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
<apex:commandButton action="goBack()" value="Cancel" immediate="true" /> <!-- I added immediate = true to avoid validations other wise it is asking to eneter required fields -->

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Just use a vanilla html button instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `onclick` function instead of `action`, as `action` looks for methods of the Controller.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
<apex:commandButton onclick="javascript:goBack()" value="Cancel" immediate="true" /> 

</apex:page>
```

Or, just in case if you want to use standard Controller's cancel then use

```
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true"  action="{!cancel}"/>
```